# TypeScript: Extending Array.prototype.join to support tuples

Tags: typescript, types, tuples

I would like to extend `Array.prototype.join` so that if the array is a tuple, it returns a templated string type using the delimiter. I have a utility type that can do this, but however I try, `this` is always getting converted to an array when I try to use the expanded `Array` definition. Does anyone know a way to do this?

Also, I would love to find some good resources for advanced typings like this: Books, articles, videos, etc.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-JcRP0TIK-LdA-ahDJyTAOBsJgRpjvEozcoOlqq4KV0PzTUnns8SS0CCOOs7hqBOs6PFCjZ+nwXKtMQrSpK0qLwW0s6tHY7hgbQUItjM0EGLByGIYRqFQI0xBMJhLATj4IgBEEjKLtBr5oL4EBOr6SQIQAtG2AD0vFggAek0oHgXiG4MvQjH8JBST7BJtCJq0PHJu4-EssJakCYAvBuAHB7E6sXRknCH4-DMax7E4VE3F8QJXiaRhYlQApjLvtBVkQPJQRKSpWkaSJ6naYAtHsTkAA)

Code for Reference:

```
type Throw<ErrorMessage extends string> = `TypeError: ${ ErrorMessage }` & { [ Key in ErrorMessage ]: void }
   
type Join<TupleOrArray, Delimiter> =
  TupleOrArray extends [] ? '' 
  : Delimiter extends string
    ? TupleOrArray extends [infer First, ...infer Rest] | Readonly<[infer First, ...infer Rest]>
      ? First extends string | number | bigint | boolean | null | undefined
        ? Rest extends [] 
          ? `${ First }` 
          : `${ First }${ Delimiter }${ Join<Rest, Delimiter> }` 
        : Throw<'Rest must be an array of strings or empty array'>
      : TupleOrArray extends { toString: () => string }[]
        ? string
        : Throw<'StringTuple is not an array or tuple'>
    : Throw<'Delimiter must be a string'>
  ;

interface Array<T> {
  join<Delimiter>(delimiter: Delimiter): this extends infer TupleOrArray ? Join<TupleOrArray, Delimiter> : never
}

const array = ['a', 'b', 'c']
const tuple = [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ] as const

type JoinedArray = Join<typeof array, '-'>
//   ^? type JoinedArray = string

const joinedArray = array.join('-')
//    ^? const joinedArray: string
// 

type JoinedType = Join<typeof tuple, '-'>
//   ^? type JoinedType = 'a-b-c'

const joinedTuple = tuple.join('-')
//    ^? const joinedTuple: string
//
```

You can see in the above code that `joinedTuple` is just a `string`, when I want it to be 'a-b-c-'.

What am I missing?

Comment: Is this just that you're using `Array` instead of `ReadonlyArray` when targeting a readonly tuple?   As shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/w25bYW)? You could/should merge into both definitions I guess?

Comment: (whoops minor update [here](https://tsplay.dev/NBJ7pN) so the delimiter is inferred as a string literal type.)

Comment: Wow. I didn't know about the `ReadonlyArray` type! Hmm... What else am I missing? I'd totally award you the answer if you _answer rather than comment_. :)

Seriously, thank you. I had been trying to figure that out for two days.

Comment: I'll write up an answer when I get a chance (it might be tomorrow since it's close to my bedtime now)

Comment: Note that this is out of scope for the question as asked, but it seems like a bad idea that your return type for non-string array inputs is some custom `Throw` type; if you call `[new Date()].join(";")` the return type for that is a `string`, and if you change the return type to `Throw<"uh oh SpaghettiOs">` that will be unexpected for people; possibly you want to disallow such calls, but that's not the effect this has.  Personally I'd suggest just having `Join<X, Y>` return `string` if `X` is not serializable via template literal types, but of course it's up to you.

Answer (score 1):

When you use a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) on an array literal, you get a [`readonly` tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#readonly-tuple-types):

```
const tuple = ['a', 'b', 'c'] as const;
// const tuple: readonly ["a", "b", "c"]
```

Before you try to [merge](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) anything in, it's useful to ask IntelliSense what `tuple.join` is and where it comes from:

```
tuple.join;
// (method) ReadonlyArray<"a" | "b" | "c">.join(separator?: string | undefined): string
```

So the compiler is getting the `join()` method from [the `ReadonlyArray<T>` interface](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#the-readonlyarray-type), as [declared here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/a89f4168bdf26505da27c144aa4bb904c60fa00b/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1173).

---

That means if you want to merge an [overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) signature for `join()` and have it affect `tuple`, you should put it in `ReadonlyArray<T>` and not in `Array<T>`:

```
interface ReadonlyArray<T> {
  join<D extends string>(delimiter: D): Join<this, D>
}
```

Note that I've modified that signature so that the type parameter is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `string` so that the compiler knows to infer it as a string [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) and not just as `string`, as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#10676](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/10676).

And I don't see a reason to copy `this` to a new type parameter so I left it out. If you have a need for that it's fine, I guess, but it doesn't show up in the example code.

Let's test it out:

```
const joinedTuple = tuple.join('-');
// const joinedTuple: "a-b-c"
```

Looks good.

---

In practice you probably won't get your hands on many tuples of string literals that aren't also `readonly`, but if you also want to overload `join()` for mutable  arrays, you'll have to do so explicitly there too:

```
interface Array<T> {
  join<D extends string>(delimiter: D): Join<this, D>
}
```

And you can see it in action:

```
const mutableTuple: ["z", "y", "x"] = ["z", "y", "x"];
const joinedMutableTuple = mutableTuple.join(", ");
// const joinedMutableTuple: "z, y, x"
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgFgJwPYHcA8BRByEFkIDOBAhgObQQAewEAdgCYFQHAICWtpAfFALxQADGOAhYcALigASAN5ikeQiXIBfAVABkUGVADaAaQggoHKPMVEyEALqSAbkjb0oKgFCvQkKAClHtNDAArmAANhAA8ggAgtjEIAA0UAAiECFsALZsNAg8vK5QsMFhkTEIcVBUNAxMutZQAPxQAORN+VCSKWmZ2RXUdIzMrBykbY1BoRHRscaV-TUcAGYQCFAAYmwILIkAdLuLy1AASoTAdQA+RxDE9Ei0ISBouvsr65vAO3u0SyvHLNZcozWGxYvSqAxY7E4UAutEC6QARgcLvC2KQOMBoVB4UgkGFiLRMbCQiFMYEGBAFhwIPRAb8MbNqnprICBLJXiw1G1JKyZOzgCpZJ0MlllgKZL4OGg6Ykhd1llxOQVJPBkOgmnSoOlAiDEVB8XrplAkAtBpDSEwFBV0mBQAayiAmgClYUJiVDQyBjpgEgAMpDTiSAAUAEo+DwIcMXLVARHOFzYIhUGgmn6zeMwiYmLQkBj9cRDZbgEUII74yqk01ZSKVlqddBiKbhqWCgBudzo5YLYgAY2gx2ut3upTiAR4MjaACs-GgkqC5o3OFxA-RUsLsh1g5IJf5gHA2AQZQC3K5u7cQfn7Xw9E1iE1Ek14Xfmt2msyT2eMUWJlfdDenw--xfOpiCYU9aBYNsAHpIKgMCQS-MJJAQK4bjuYxdAAImIDDEgw+EcKgDDuwwt8EIgbYpw4KCYMDdIIF3JB6FDftUKHaY0CwjDMTwriLiIjCuAovxAwICAwHzYhvQQepJFjUhSXJSlaGpTcFxGd9wIxSjlPodNoH4MihI4QMmgAWiaYNqNgj8oG06k9MkLDTPhUziPcVwOwQLteygYcHhgMdJ2nWcPSYOSlxXLpqw3Ldp13fdD1cY84IxLVgGIeEwgcvQMIALwIjCQAKygSJ-PKCqK3CSusNsUtsvxqVwQJ0syiA9KvNKMqy4sjNoQMCss1xoOszT6qpegmpa7qJkc3LEgSKASvcurjH4QNdGUlBkkkiAQ2A0CP2DXr+pKwbhpW5VE3QDCNVrDFdTzAsTTki0Vgga1bQvOIBKgYa0FM0yoHisKIHeph4WuIGkE1CBXCAA)